# C# smtpfailedrecipientsexception; How to exit function if this happens

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

So here is my code which is used to send emails from Unity using a C# script:

```
public void SendMail() // Mail send function
    {
        string emailAddress; // variable to store user inputted email 
        emailAddress = emailInput.text; // variable becomes the email the user types in
        mail.From = new MailAddress("hiddenfornow");
        mail.To.Add(emailAddress);
        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpServer.Port = 587;
        mail.Subject = "Test Subject" + currentDate;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true; // allows for html
        mail.Body = "Testing testing";
        smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hiddenfornow", "hiddenfornow") as ICredentialsByHost;
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestScene"); // reloads the scene after user clicks button         
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        Debug.Log("success");
}
```

This code is working fine to send emails. However, if i enter an incorrect email i will recieve an "smtpfailedrecipientsexception" message.

After this, even entering a correct email address will not work. The smtpfailedrecipientsexception will continue to occur unless you type it correct the first time.

I would like to add some kind of If statement such as this which i've written in pseudocode:

```
If smtpserver.send(mail)returns smtp error
{
Exit this function
}
else
{
success message
}
```

I am just not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SmtpClient` uses pooling to reduce the overhead of creating new connections to the server. (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

My assumption is that the `SmtpFailedRecientsException` is putting the connection into a bad state, so you need to force the connection to close by disposing the client:

```
public void SendMail() // Mail send function
    {
        //your code...

        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        try {
            //.... your code continues.....
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
            Debug.Log("success");
        } catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException) { //or, perhaps any Exception
            smtpServer.Dispose();
            throw; //rethrow the exception, assuming you're handling it in the calling code
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your comment guided me towards my solution. The try catch worked but the smtpServer.Dispose(); was not working. However, i tried mail.Dispose(); and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use exception handling approach to dealing with runtime exception :

```
        try
        {
            if (smtpserver.send(mail))
                return "successful";
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
        {
            // log your error
            return ex.StatusCode; // return status code as you will know actual error code
        }
        finally
        {
            mail.Dispose(); // Dispose your mailmessage as it will clears any stream associated with your mail message such as attachment

        }
```

[Available Status Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help, mail.Dispose(); was what i needed, i combined your answer with John's post to reach a solution!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is the code which worked:

```
Try
{
smtpServer.Send(mail); // Attempts to send the email
Debug.Log("success");
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException) // Catches send failure
{
mail.Dispose(); // ends the SMTP connection
SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName"); //Reloads the scene to clear textboxes
}
```

Comment: Better to have disposing implementation in finally block. Best if you would use `using` statement instead of manually disposing `MailMessage` object